# Possible to make vscode use a proxy upstream of remote-ssh?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, tunnel

#### question:

Is there any way to tunnel all outgoing ssh connections in vscode (including those established by the remote-ssh plugin) through my on-site workstation?  I have full control over the firewall for that machine and can open ports on ufw as needed for off-site access.

#### background:

I use vscode remote-ssh to connect to a research computing cluster when on-site.
For remote work, I would like to avoid using cisco anyconnect as a vpn in mac os 11.6, as routing and other os features behave unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out in mac os, it's sufficient to edit the ~/.ssh/config file by specifying an on-site proxy host that I control within the `ProxyCommand` option:

```
Host clusterNode
  ProxyCommand  ssh me@my_accessible_ssh_host nc %h %p
  HostName <firewalled node ip address>
  User my_cluster_username
```